# CheckChanged event isn't firing when one box unchecks another

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have two checkboxes on a page:

```
<anthem:CheckBox ID="chk1"  Text="Include Deactivated Users" runat="server" AutoCallBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk1_CheckedChanged" />

<anthem:CheckBox ID="chk2" Text="Exclude Deactivated Users" runat="server"  AutoCallBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk2_CheckedChanged" />
```

Code behind for CheckedChanged events:

```
protected void chk1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //calls some random functions to check stuff

    lstUsers.UpdateAfterCallBack = true; //updates a checkboxlist 'lstUsers'
    chkAllUsers.UpdateAfterCallBack = true; //updates another checkbox
}

protected void chk2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (box.Checked == true)
    {          
        chk1.Checked = !box.Checked;
    }
}
```

Here's the conditions I want:

1. `chk1` is checked. `chk2` is unchecked. `chk2` is then checked, which causes `chk1` to uncheck and fire it's event.
2. `chk2` is checked. `chk1` is unchecked. `chk1` is then checked, which causes `chk2` to uncheck and fire it's event.

I'm only working on `1.` right now, because if I get that working I can make the second work. The problem I'm having is, when `chk2` is checked, it unchecks `chk1` but `chk1_CheckedChanged` is never fired.

`chk1_CheckedChanged` does in work on it's own when checking/unchecking.

The weird thing is, if I check, uncheck, then check `chk2`, `chk1_CheckedChanged` gets fired but `chk1` never changes, then `chk2_CheckedChanged` is fired.

I'm confused on what exactly is happening here.

I've messed around with AutoPostBack for the two `checkboxes` as that seemed to be a solution in similar problems but had no luck with that either.

Comment: Sorry just edited my post, I've tried doing that. I've set the AutoPostBack for each separately, as well as together but still didn't work.

Comment: Look like your checkboxes fire corresponding CheckedChanged event correctly. You need to figure out the business logic.

Comment: Hmm. Not having any luck. It doesn't make sense to me that a checkedchange event isn't happening when the checkbox is in fact changed.

Comment: You better encapsulate the code in chk1_CheckedChanged onto a method, then you can call that method in your chk2_CheckedChanged, without expecting trigger an event from an another control.

Comment: But the code in `chk1_CheckedChanged` needs to be called only from that. `chk2` should be able to check/uncheck without calling stuff from `chk1_CheckedChanged`.

Comment: Looks like you're using a third-party AJAX product. These aren't ASP.NET checkboxes, but Anthem ones. I'd update your question and tags to make this known so you can get specific help. I'm not familiar with the library, but have you tried setting AutoUpdateAfterCallBack to true on your control declarations? According to the docs, the controls won't be updated by default and you aren't setting both the checkboxes' UpdateAfterCallBack properties in your server-side code either. BTW, AutoPostBack is for ASP.NET controls, AutoCallBack appears to be the Anthem equivalent.

Comment: Figured it out. @JCM I did something like you said and it seems to work now. Thank you Dave for the info!